# (Dependantly?) typing containers

Tags: generic-programming, shapeless, hlist

Given a type constructor/container `F[_]` I want to make a combinator which can compose polymorphic types and hlist types into a new container by the following ruleset:

- `F[HNil]` and `F[HNil]` into a `F[HNil]`
- `F[A]` and `F[HNil]` into a `F[A :: HNil]`
- `F[HNil]` and `F[A]` into a `F[A :: HNil]`
- `F[A]` and `F[B]` into a `F[A :: B :: HNil]`
- `F[L <: HList]` and `F[R <: HList]` into a `F[L :: R]` (hlist concat)
- `F[A]` and `F[R <: HList]` into a `F[A :: R]` (hlist prepend)
- `F[L <: HList]` and `F[B]` into a `F[L :: B :: HNil]` (hlist append)

Is there a nice way to do this in shapeless? Or is there a easier way to solve this particular problem :) The thing is that I have combinators which yield a `F[Int]`, `F[HNil]` and `F[HNil]`. Combining these should not yield a `F[Int :: HNil :: HNil]` (but `F[Int :: HNil]`) for example. For this purpose now I've made typeclass:

```
 trait CodecAppender[F, A, B] {
  type Out
  final type CodecOut = Codec[F, Out]
  def apply(a: Codec[F, A], b: Codec[F, B]): CodecOut
}

object CodecAppender {

  type Aux[F, A, B, C] = CodecAppender[F, A, B] { type Out = C }

  private def make[F, A, B, C](decompose: C => (A, B))(implicit S: Monoid[F], D: DecoderAppender.Aux[F, A, B, C]): Aux[F, A, B, C] = new CodecAppender[F, A, B] {
    type Out = C

    def apply(a: Codec[F, A], b: Codec[F, B]): CodecOut = new Codec[F, C] {
      def encode(in: C) = {
        val (head, tail) = decompose(in)
        a.encode(head) |+| b.encode(tail)
      }

      val decoder = D.append(a.decoder, b.decoder)
    }
  }

  implicit def HNilAndHNil[F, O](implicit M: Monoid[F],
                                 D: DecoderAppender.Aux[F, HNil, HNil, HNil]) =
    make[F, HNil, HNil, HNil](r => HNil -> HNil)

  //other cases omitted, but there are 6 more (which I described above)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice way of doing just that using a series of type classes. You can do something if your `F[_]` has an instance of an `Monad`:

```
trait Conv[A]{
  type Out <: HList
  def apply(a: A): Out
}

object Conv extends LowPrior{
  implicit def hlist[L <: HList] = new Conv[L]{
    type Out = L
    def apply(hl: L) = hl
  }
}

trait LowPrior{
  implicit def other[A] = new Conv[A]{
    type Out = H :: HNil
    def apply(a: A) = a :: HNil
  }
}

def combineF[F[_], A, B](fa: F[A], fb: F[B])(implicit ca: Conv[A], cb: Conv[B], m: Monad[F]) = m.flatMap(fa){ a: A =>
  m.map(fb){ b: B => ca(a) ::: c(b) }
}
```

If you want the real return types you could define an `Aux` type in `Conv` companion object and then use the `Prepend` type class of an `HList` to get the final realized result type. (I'm actually fairly positive you could achieve the same thing with an `Applicative` or even a `Zip` type class. Will leave that up to you to discover.)

Comment: Thanks for the simple implementation! It's quite easy to use Applicative for combineF (cats): `(fa.map(ca) |@| fb.map(cb)) map (_ ::: _)`. Instead of `m: Monad[F]` you would only need `Applicative[F]`

Answer (score 1):

Scodec is doing something like that :

```
  def prepend[A, L <: HList](a: Codec[A], l: Codec[L]): Codec[A :: L] = new Codec[A :: L] {
    override def sizeBound = a.sizeBound + l.sizeBound
    override def encode(xs: A :: L) = Codec.encodeBoth(a, l)(xs.head, xs.tail)
    override def decode(buffer: BitVector) = Codec.decodeBothCombine(a, l)(buffer) { _ :: _ }
    override def toString = s"$a :: $l"
  }
```

https://github.com/scodec/scodec/blob/ac71016dcea61cc6aaabe4f4dff4ab5bf13ac239/shared/src/main/scala/scodec/codecs/HListCodec.scala#L19-L25